# Bootstrap column change order on mobile (1,2,3 in 2,1,3)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I found a solution on the mobile how to change order for two cloumn. My situation is that of 3 columns 1,2,3 and I don't know how the order 2,1,3 is on the mobile.

Please help me with a solution.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to code your project but I can give you an idea with an example situation.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col ">
      First, goes second.
    </div>
    <div class="col order-first">
      Second, goes first.
    </div>
    <div class="col order-last">
      Third, goes last.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you follow the codes above you can solve the problem. On the other hands you can visit the original web site of Bootstrap for this kind of problems.

I have the solution from this link.(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Second option could be coding media query as a custom CSS. You can search about it as well.

I hope these goes weel and you can solve it.

Best.